# Update SQLite com EditText Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sql-update, sqlite3, edittext

Bom dia senhores, estou tentando fazer um update no meu banco de dados no SQLite através do meu EditText porém ele apresenta erro, alguém poderia me dizer no que estou errando ?

```
public void insererazaosocial (SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL( "UPDATE emitente SET razaosocial='"+selecinfo2.getText().toString()+"' WHERE id = 1");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal consegui resolver o problema, caso queiram um exemplo podem pegar o meu código para vocês. Forte abraço :D

```
public void insererazaosocial (SQLiteDatabase db){

        String valor = selecinfo2.getText().toString();
        if (valor != null) {
            db.execSQL("UPDATE emitente SET razaosocial='"+valor+"' WHERE id = 1");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O registro foi gravado no Banco de Dados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Verifique as informações e tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```